# Onclick active class not working along with navbar show/hide

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need help to do below stuffs work,

1. make navbar show/hide on scroll
2. active class on nav-links'a `a`  tag according to viewport also same would be work on click..

```js
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
console.log("Prev Position is", prevScrollpos);

window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  console.log("Current Position is", currentScrollPos);
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("navbarSection").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbarSection").style.top = "-70px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
};


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

  //smoothscroll
  $('a[href^="#"]').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off("scroll");

    $("a").each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
    $(this).addClass("active");

    var target = this.hash,
      menu = target;
    $target = $(target);
    $("html, body")
      .stop()
      .animate({
          scrollTop: $target.offset().top + 2,
        },
        500,
        "swing",
        function() {
          window.location.hash = target;
          $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        }
      );
  });
});

function onScroll(event) {
  var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
  $("#navbarSection a").each(function() {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
    if (
      refElement.position().top <= scrollPos &&
      refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos
    ) {
      $("#navbarSection ul li a").removeClass("active");
      currLink.addClass("active");
    } else {
      currLink.removeClass("active");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif !important;
}

#navbarSection {
  position: sticky !important;
  background: white !important;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s !important;
}

Section {
  margin-bottom: 150px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.blue-button {
  padding: 12px 24px !important;
  background-color: #3130F2 !important;
  border-radius: 37px !important;
  color: white !important;
  font-weight: 700 !important;
}

.blue-button:hover {
  background-color: #FECD00 !important;
  /* color: #3130F2 !important; */
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s !important;
}

.closeButton {
  background-color: rgba(254, 205, 0, 0.4);
  /* border: none; */
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.closeButton:hover {
  background-color: rgba(254, 205, 0, 0.8);
  /* background-color: rgba(49, 48, 242, 0.5) ; */
  /* border: none; */
  border: 1px solid #3130f2;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.offcanvas-backdrop.show {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.offcanvas-backdrop {
  background-color: #8E90A6;
}

.closeIcon {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.nav-link {
  padding: 0px !important;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px !important;
  line-height: 40px !important;
  letter-spacing: 0.08em !important;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: #3130F2 !important;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #FECD00 !important;
  cursor: pointer !important;
  transition: all .18s ease-in-out 0s !important;
}

.nav-item:active a {
  background-color: #8E90A6 !important;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link.active,
.navbar-nav .show>.nav-link {
  color: #3130F2 !important;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 37px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #FECD00;
}

.btn:hover {
  border-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <!-- google fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />


  <!-- bootstrap 5.2.0 -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <title>Navbar on scroll</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container" id="navbarSection">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" aria-label="Offcanvas navbar large">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#heroSection"><img src="./Assets/logo.svg" alt="" /></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasNavbar2" aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar2" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end mx-auto" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasNavbar2" aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbar2Label">
          <div class="offcanvas-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#heroSection"><img src="./Assets/logo.svg" alt="" /></a>
            <button type="button" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close" class="closeButton">
                <img
                  class="closeIcon"
                  src="./Assets/cross.png"
                  alt="Close Icon"
                />
              </button>
            <!-- <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button> -->
          </div>
          <div class="offcanvas-body">
            <ul class="navbar-nav align-items-center mx-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item heroSection">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#heroSection">About Us</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item serviceSection">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#serviceSection">Services</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item workSection">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#workSection">Work</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="contact-us-button">
              <button class="btn blue-button">
                  <a
                    href="#contactSection"
                    style="text-decoration: none; color: white"
                    >Contact Us</a
                  >
                </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <section id="heroSection">
  </section>
  <section id="workSection">
  </section>
  <section id="aboutusSection">
  </section>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This took some fixing, so I managed to fix the on click  that was failing because the image was acting as the link and not the a href, then I had to fix the code to get the href src attribute from the element which was tricky because this was referring to the image so I had to find it and although it was right next to it, closest didn't seem to want to find it, anyway then was failing here

```
 var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
    if (
      refElement.position().top <= scrollPos &&
```

because the html was missing the elements tfor the corisponding a href src's

```
  <section id="aboutusSection">
    </section>
<section id="contactSection">
    </section>
```

```js
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
console.log("Prev Position is", prevScrollpos);
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  console.log("Current Position is", currentScrollPos);
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("navbarSection").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbarSection").style.top = "-70px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

  //smoothscroll
  $(".navbar-toggler").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off("scroll");

    $(".closeIcon").on("click", function(e) {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
    $(this).addClass("active");

    var target = $(this).parents("div.container-fluid").find(".navbar-brand").attr("href")
    menu = target;
    $target = $(target);
    $("html, body")
      .stop()
      .animate({
          scrollTop: $target.offset().top + 2,
        },
        500,
        "swing",
        function() {
          window.location.hash = target;
          $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        }
      );
  });
});

function onScroll(event) {
  var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
  $("#navbarSection a").each(function() {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
    if (
      refElement.position().top <= scrollPos &&
      refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos
    ) {
      $("#navbarSection ul li a").removeClass("active");
      currLink.addClass("active");
    } else {
      currLink.removeClass("active");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif !important;
}

#navbarSection {
  position: sticky !important;
  background: white !important;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s !important;
}

Section {
  margin-bottom: 150px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.blue-button {
  padding: 12px 24px !important;
  background-color: #3130F2 !important;
  border-radius: 37px !important;
  color: white !important;
  font-weight: 700 !important;
}

.blue-button:hover {
  background-color: #FECD00 !important;
  /* color: #3130F2 !important; */
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out 0s !important;
}

.closeButton {
  background-color: rgba(254, 205, 0, 0.4);
  /* border: none; */
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.closeButton:hover {
  background-color: rgba(254, 205, 0, 0.8);
  /* background-color: rgba(49, 48, 242, 0.5) ; */
  /* border: none; */
  border: 1px solid #3130f2;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.offcanvas-backdrop.show {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.offcanvas-backdrop {
  background-color: #8E90A6;
}

.closeIcon {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.nav-link {
  padding: 0px !important;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px !important;
  line-height: 40px !important;
  letter-spacing: 0.08em !important;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: #3130F2 !important;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #FECD00 !important;
  cursor: pointer !important;
  transition: all .18s ease-in-out 0s !important;
}

.nav-item:active a {
  background-color: #8E90A6 !important;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link.active,
.navbar-nav .show>.nav-link {
  color: #3130F2 !important;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 37px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #FECD00;
}

.btn:hover {
  border-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

  <!-- google fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />


  <!-- bootstrap 5.2.0 -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <title>Navbar on scroll</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container" id="navbarSection">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" aria-label="Offcanvas navbar large">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#heroSection"><img src="./Assets/logo.svg" alt="" /></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasNavbar2" aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar2" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end mx-auto" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasNavbar2" aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbar2Label">
          <div class="offcanvas-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#heroSection"><img src="./Assets/logo.svg" alt="" /></a>
            <button type="button" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close" class="closeButton">
                <img class="closeIcon" src="./Assets/cross.png" alt="Close Icon" />
              </button>
            <!-- <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button> -->
          </div>
          <div class="offcanvas-body">
            <ul class="navbar-nav align-items-center mx-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item heroSection">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#heroSection">About Us</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item serviceSection">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#serviceSection">Services</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item workSection">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#workSection">Work</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="contact-us-button">
              <button class="btn blue-button">
                  <a href="#contactSection" style="text-decoration: none; color: white">Contact Us</a>
                </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <section id="heroSection">
  </section>
  <section id="workSection">
  </section>
  <section id="aboutusSection">
  </section>
  <section id="serviceSection">
  </section>
  <section id="contactSection">
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

and so it runs bug-free and the on-click works, I hope this helps